# Javascript Event Bubbling/Caputuring

Tags: javascript

Since every browser works different, whats the approach for a well working website?
I Mean i cannot know if I want attach it to bubbling or capturing phase since I don't know what the different Browser do first. And I don't want to write code for every browser. Corrent me if I'm wrong, but I read that every browser acts different.
So do I have to add a listener to every "child-widget" i have on the website and do `stopPropagation()` and `cancelBubble = true;` in every listener to have wanted behaviour for sure?

Comment: Use jQuery. For this is (also) intended, you will have unified behaviour across browsers.

Comment: Could you show a code sample that is giving you a problem?

Comment: This depends very much on which browsers you need to support. Newer browsers usually handle events according to the standards, so you wouldn't have to worry. What is your use-case (in code) and which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Mean i cannot know if I want attach it to bubbling or capturing
>   phase since I don't know what the different Browser do first.

The behavior of events is fully defined in the DOM spec. The capture phase happens before the bubble one. See the following graphic from [Event dispatch and DOM event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#event-flow):

[image: graphical representation of an event dispatched in a DOM tree using the DOM event flow]

Modern browsers are compliant.

> Correct me if I'm wrong, but I read that every browser acts different.

Only old browsers behave unreliably.